Redis Stack: Storing JSON document, Deduplicate on property
I have a JSON document coming into Redis that contains a directory path.
Key: "idx:sys:ikSh-pEBejscyM5jrSyY"
"path";"/root/fred/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3"

I may end up getting a feed that contains a duplicate path.
Key: "idx:sys:h0Sh-pEBejscyM5jrSyX"
"path";"/root/fred/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3"

My goal is to deduplicate keys with the same path.
I have been using Redis for a while, but I am new to Redis Stack.
I'm storing my documents as JSON, using JSON.SET
Some of the paths may contain hyphens.
I have created an index.
FT.CREATE idx:sys
    ON  JSON
    PREFIX 1 fred:sys:
SCHEMA
    $.path AS path_tag TAG SORTABLE
    $.path AS path_text TEXT SORTABLE
    $.target.fspace AS filespace TEXT

If I run an ft.search, I get duplicate entries.
 FT.SEARCH idx:sys "*" SORTBY path_text DESC  RETURN 1 $.path 
1) (integer) 2
2) "lucid:blansys:ikSh-pEBejscyM5jrSyY"
3) 1) "$.path"
   2) "/root/fred/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3"
4) "lucid:blansys:h0Sh-pEBejscyM5jrSyX"
5) 1) "$.path"
   2) "/root/fred/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3"

Do you have any pointers on how I can remove keys that have duplicate entries for the path?
Thank you so much for your attention and participation.

I have played with FT.TAGVALS, which does return distinct values.
FT.TAGVALS idx:sys path_tag
However, I don't know how to get the keys with those results and how to delete the key that where duplicates.

I think I found the solution and posting to see if it helps anyone else.
I needed to alter my index slightly;
My keys are built using a JSON property from the doc;
fred:sys:<docId>

So, I added this field to my Schema.
FT.CREATE idx:sys
    ON  JSON
    PREFIX 1 fred:sys:
SCHEMA
    $.path AS path_tag TAG SORTABLE
    $.path AS path_text TEXT SORTABLE
    $.target.fspace AS filespace TEXT
    $.docId AS docid TAG SORTABLE NOINDEX

Then, using FT.AGGREGATE, I got distinct path values and all the Redis keys in which they occurred.
FT.AGGREGATE idx:entryPath * GROUPBY 1 @path_text REDUCE TOLIST 1 @docid as docids

results
1) (integer) 4
2) 1) "path_text"
   2) "/root/fred/subfolder1/sub-folder2/sub folder"
   3) "docids"
   4) 1) "h0Sh-pEBejscyM5jrSyX"
3) 1) "path_text"
   2) "/root/fred/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder"
   3) "docids"
   4) 1) "h0Sh-pEBejscyM5krSyX"
4) 1) "path_text"
   2) "/root/fred/sub-folder1/sub folder2/sub-folder3"
   3) "docids"
   4) 1) "ikSh-pEBejscyM5jrSyY"
5) 1) "path_text"
   2) "/root/fred/subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3"
   3) "docids"
   4) 1) "RFGC-5EB2UfWbJjp5QCt"
      2) "ikSh-pEBejsczyM5jrSyY"
      3) "R1GC-5EB2UfWbJjp5QCt"

I'm calling this from Node.js; I clean up the returned array using array.shift() and array.split(). This leaves me with an array containing the path and a nested array of keys.
Then, convert the array into a JSON object using a mustache template.
Now I can process each distinct path in the target system I'm updating and run through the keys array to delete them from Redis once done.
Hope this helps someone else.
